# Excel M query: Permission issue

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to access investing.com from excel 2016 using power query, I am getting a permission issue, is there a way to bypass it? It worked till yesterday, but now I am still getting this error even though I passed the cookie and header information in the URL. Below are the error and code
Error: [Permission Error] The credentials provided for the web source are invalid. Please update the credentials through a refresh or in the Data Source settings dialog to continue. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
let
Source = ()=> Web.Contents("https://tvc6.investing.com/de339cb1628af015d591805dfffe9b13/1663439222/1/1/8/quotes?symbols=NSE%20%3ANSEI",[Headers=[#"accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate",#"cookie"="jLeqXJArEhTZVUQpwiP1gSPVlhn19b3fsB7uRcSUbyg-1666154846-0-AR2gelOI/3ZaH0SKRFuxhsgOGr/SOXpnbQ7e90mYM2iDmpTf8XcvvIB/FvGtgkB50nccnbWB1rFawcO37vJpSBU=",#"accept-language"="en-US,en;q=0.9",#"user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.47"]])   
in
    Source
```

Comment: I assume the cookie expired ?

Comment: @horseyride, No, the cookie I immediately copied after I visited the site for testing purpose.